# Wait based on time or action

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to create a journey that email one of my dealers when there is a new lead.
In the email, the dealer needs to click on 2 buttons: `Accept` or `Decline`.
If after 48 hours he didn't clicked on anything, the field of the response will automatically changes to `Decline` and the process start again by sending email to the next dealer in the DE.

Added in edit:*I want that if the dealer clicks on Accept, even if it is 1 hour after the email was sent, it will right away continue the journey.*

Is it something possible to create from the journey builder?
How can I notify the lead after there is a match with dealer from within the journey?
If it is possible, can it be done from one journey?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Advance someone in a Journey based on an event in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264099/advance-someone-in-a-journey-based-on-an-event-in-salesforce) which details in depth how the "Wait until event occurs" is not currently supported.
That said, there was plans at one point called "Wait Until Event" which would do exactly what you need but it was canned. Some people were in pilot and here is a couple of screenshots :) 
[image]
[image]